# java.util.logging XMLFormatter Schema?

Tags: java, logging, xsd

What is the formal definition of the schema of messages created by java.util.logging.XMLFormatter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[DTD for XMLFormatter Output](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#3.0)